# Glyphicon showing above mobile menu

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons, mmenu

I'm using a Glyphicon inside of a div to open up the mobile menu called Mmenu on mobile devices. The action works fine, but the Glyphicon shows above the menu rather than hidden below it. I've changed the Mmenu's and Glyphicon's z-index to 100 and 99 respectively but still nothing.
I suspect it's related to another issue that's causing the page content to slide over but not the header where the div is contained?

Is anyone able to help me understand why?

Thanks.

[website](http://radshaperc.businesscatalyst.com)

Comment: If you want help you need to post your code and markup.  An image can be helpful as well as a jsFiddle that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Ha! It probably would have helped, huh? Sorry, here's the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ConduciveMammal/zeagfxzs/). It seems I can't post images but here's an [Imgur link](http://imgur.com/ARasuv2). Thanks. Also, Ignore the fact the hamburger Glyphicon isn't showing, it went awry after putting it into JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why the problem is happening, but you can work around it with this CSS:

```
.mm-menu {
    z-index: 200 !important;
}
```

This puts the fixed menu panel above the icon.

> Updated **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/zeagfxzs/1/)**

Comment: Ahh fantastic! Yeah I wasn't sure either, logically, it should have worked but just wouldn't.  Thanks a lot for the help!